# gulp-minify-css plugin issues with 'advanced features'

Tags: css, gulp

Just started using gulp and noticed something peculiar:

If you look at https://ide.c9.io/jmsherry/gulp_minify_css_issue#openfile-README.md

...you'll see that the background declaration before minification is 'background: none scroll 0 0 no-repeat #5F9EA0;' but then becomes 
'background:no-repeat none' when gulp-minify-css operation occurs. If you shuffle the values around, then different ones will appear in the minified declaration.

A solution to this problem is to specify 'noAdvanced: true' in the options you pass to gulp-minify-css, but then you lose the benefits of that feature. What I'm wondering is why it does it and is there another way around it?

Comment: As we're knee deep in pedants I thought I'd put this here:

IT IS NOT THE ANSWER TO THE QUESTION. Getting a bit bored of the downvotes - this is supposed to be a community and I can't know the answer to this question until the people who make the product debug it... then I'll give you the answer. Until then:

Bug is with clean-css (https://github.com/GoalSmashers/clean-css) - looks like they've had a few (https://github.com/GoalSmashers/clean-css/issues/316). Just worth knowing if you were going to use it commercially...

Comment: To clarify, as somehow I now can't edit the above comment, if you user the advanced features flag then you risk having your declarations destroyed in the minification process. If you watch the ticket mentioned above (316) then you'll get an answer as to when it's been fixed; until then I'd recommend setting 'noAdvanced' to 'true'.

Comment: What you're saying is mostly what I did, except your link to the related issue. A comment is here more suitable than an answer.

Comment: @Aperçu Yes, your comment was helpful - that's why I upvoted it.

It depends what you count as an answer - at this rate there will be no answer because those who run clean-css will not give an answer why it's happening, they will just fix it. So you see this question is actually unanswerable. Even if we did get an answer it wouldn't help anyone - there's nothing they could do with that information?!

I gave it as an answer because basically it answers the question as far as needs to be answered and it will help others understand that it is a bug and that they must watch the issue for updates.

Comment: Yes you've got a point, until the issue is fixed we can't go any further

Answer (score 1):

The `noAdvanced` attribute of [clean-css](https://github.com/GoalSmashers/clean-css/), which is the CSS minifier used by `gulp-minify-css` disable some optimizations and propreties merging.

I think that this feature is not perfect yet and can be improved. In your case, your `background` proprety is not very common, and the minifier output randomly depending on what you gave it first, so :

```
background: none scroll 0 0 no-repeat #5F9EA0;
```

Don't understand that many parameters, so it simply cut everything he think not belongs here.

Disabling this feature can help you to keep the desired behaviour.

Comment: Hi @Aperçu,
I think that that's the issue - I think clean-css isn't developed enough yet. ^^ is a standard background declaration, so I don't know what it struggles with? I don't know why it strips different vars depending on the order you wrote them...??

I think it's worth having this here so that others are aware of it...